# Where Are My Class Members in Solution explorer in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, solution-explorer

I recently installed Visual Studio Ultimate after using the Express edition(WD). I have since noticed that the solution explorer does not show my files members anymore.

I was wondering if this is either by design or has something gone wrong when I installed Ultimate after Express?

Comment: Thanks, Obviously its a fault with the install. Ill un-install all components and re-install and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling ALL components of VS2012 and re-installing them did the trick. Unsure why such a small feature was missing when everything else worked great.